# twitter API: Full Archive/Sandbox

Tags: api, search, twitter, rstudio, archive

I am relatively new to R but doing my best to do perform a historical twitter search using Rstudio and twitteR package. I recently was granted access to the Full Archive/Sandbox search via my twitter dev account, however I cannot seem to get any results when I add the "since=" and "until=" parameters to the searchTwitter function. When I remove these parameters, the app works fine and I get recent results only...

```
# this returns a dataframe of tweets

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, 
access_secret)
tw <- searchTwitter('soccer', n = 14)
tw <- twListToDF(tw)
```

adding 'since' and 'until' gives the following result

```
tw <- searchTwitter('soccer', n = 14, since = '2018-01-01', until = 
'2018-01-10')
tw <- twListToDF(tw)

Warning message:
In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = 
retryOnRateLimit,  :
14 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0
```

In my twitter dev account, I have created a dev environment and associated the sandbox account with the app I was previously using to get limited recent tweets only. Not sure what I have to change in order to get access to the full archive.

Answer (score 2):

The `twitteR` package only works for Twitter Standard APIs, not Premium APIs.

Please see the [premium Search API docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search.html#DataEndpoint) for reference. If you are familiar with Python, I have a library [here](https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-python) you might find useful to work with the API. There are code samples [here](https://twitterdev.github.io/search-tweets-python/#using-the-twitter-search-apis-python-wrapper) that will get you running quickly.

Comment: With regard to the gen_rule_payload function, I understand this takes a powertrack rule in the form of a string, but the following rule does not seem to work with the premium operators "lang:en" "sample:50" "place_country:us" - do you have any suggestions? without the operators, the code runs well, with them it fails, many thanks for your help - gen_rule_payload("(infection OR disease) ( pneumonia OR cellulitis OR wound OR laceration OR fever) sample:50 lang:en place_country:us", from_date="2012-02-01", to_date="2012-03-01", results_per_call =100)

Comment: You're welcome. I assume you're using a sandbox environment? the `sample:x` operator is not available in the sandbox environment afaik.

Comment: I'm actually using the paid premium environment now and still having this problem

Comment: the `place_country` operator wasn't available until early 2015. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/fas-timeline -